# jQuery function toggle() is not working in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have been unable to make this toggle() function work on my wordpress site, although it works in codepen. Here is the code:

```
<style>    
footer {
background: #163774; 
color: #ffffff; 
font-weight: bold;  
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
position: fixed;   
text-align: center; 
transition: 2s bottom;
}

.minimizer {
background-color:#FC7F0C; 
padding: 3px; 
border-top-left-radius: 15px;
border-top-right-radius: 15px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
cursor: pointer; 
}
</style>


<footer class="hidden">
    <div class="minimizer">

   <h1>Header</h1>
   </div>

    <span class="form_content">
        Text Here
    </span>
</footer>


<script>
    $('.minimizer').click(function() {
      $('span.form_content').toggle()
    });
</script>
```

I have my scripts sourced properly and the jQuery library sourced in the header.php template file. I use the same code in codepen and it works, but when I put it all into my site it doesn't work.

Comment: whats the site called?

Comment: as written, it should work just fine. problem is not in the provided code. Please provide an example that recreates the problem.

Comment: Have you used document-ready handler, Try once with wrapping your code in `$(function(){ //Your code})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your functions inside jQuery .ready() method to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.minimizer').click(function() {
     $('span.form_content').toggle();
    });
 });
</script>
```